# How can I rotate jfr files for long running application?

Tags: java, jfr

I have enabled jfr for my application during start-up by adding the following JFR options in the command.

```
JFR_OPTS="-XX=UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -Djava.net.IPv4Stack=true -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=stackdepth=128 -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,dumponexit=true,dumponexitpath=$APP_HOME/logs/$APP_NAME_$NOW.jfr"
```

Since my application is long running and will be up for 6 days a week, I am a bit confused if the jfr file created on exit will be created continuously recording all events since starting the application till exit after 6 days or it will overwrite the file like FIFO or rotate like log file. Any clarification please?

Answer (score 0):

Ohh my previous answer was incomplete, to rotate you need to use the maxage and/or maxsixe:

IE for maxage:

```
-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,dumponexit=true,dumponexitpath=$APP_HOME/logs/$APP_NAME_$NOW.jfr,maxage=24h
```

With that config it creates a new JFR file every 24 hours with a timestamp added to the filename; or try with the maxsize

```
-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,dumponexit=true,dumponexitpath=$APP_HOME/logs/$APP_NAME_$NOW.jfr,maxsize=1g
```

With that config it creates a new JFR file every time the current file size reaches 1 GB, with a timestamp added to the filename.

Just one tip, use the defaultrecording=false option instead of defaultrecording=true, this will prevent JFR from automatically starting a new recording each time the JVM starts..

Comment: I tried adding these parameters with the updated command
JFR_OPTS="-XX=UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -Djava.net.IPv4Stack=true -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=stackdepth=128 -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,dumponexit=true,dumponexitpath=$APP_HOME/logs/$APP_NAME_$NOW.jfr,maxage=1h,disk=true"
But it created the file only after shutting down the component instead of from start up. So I could no capture the profiling when there was an exception as the file was not created. How can I turn on profiling from application start up?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle JDK 8, recordings are by default recorded to memory, which means about 12 MB will be kept, not including thread local buffers (2 KB/thread).

If disk=true is set, the last 15 minutes will be kept on disk. No limit on size. The retention policy can be set with maxage=... and maxsize=..., i.e. maxage=1h,maxsize=500MB

(In JDK 9+ and Oracle EPP, recordings are to disk by default and 250 MB kept, no limit on age.)